# Need assistance concatenating a string request together in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, concatenation, grouping

In JavaScript I am sending an https request to a server. I receive the data back I am looking for but it comes in batches. Depending on the size of the data I'm requesting could be from 2-50 different batches. I need to get them all together so I can parse and pull the data I need from an array. The data I receive is pasted below. You can see there is a date and time stamp at the beginning of the first batch and another after "rows":. Those are added by the debugger I am using which is how I know they come in separate. My question is:

1) How do i get the strings concatenated together

2) Which is the best way to get in an array so I can choose the data I want?

```js
2018 - 03 - 08 T21: 09: 18.913 Z f657fe40 - 2314 - 11e8 - 8273 - 19289 d6ed567 {
  "id": 12345678,
  "name": "Dummy sheet",
  "version": 1,
  "totalRowCount": 1,
  "accessLevel": "ADMIN",
  "effectiveAttachmentOptions": ["BOX_COM", "GOOGLE_DRIVE", "FILE", "EGNYTE", "ONEDRIVE", "DROPBOX", "EVERNOTE"],
  "ganttEnabled": false,
  "dependenciesEnabled": false,
  "resourceManagementEnabled": false,
  "cellImageUploadEnabled": true,
  "userSettings": {
    "criticalPathEnabled": false,
    "displaySummaryTasks": true
  },
  "permalink": "https://app.smartsheet.com/b/home?lx=rxeuvsB26BVmyEpa6OYxUA",
  "createdAt": "2018-03-06T14:29:32Z",
  "modifiedAt": "2018-03-06T14:51:59Z",
  "columns": [{
    "id": 3114821425096580,
    "index": 0,
    "title": "Primary Column",
    "type": "TEXT_NUMBER",
    "primary": true,
    "validation": false,
    "width": 150
  }, {
    "id": 7618421052467076,
    "index": 1,
    "title": "Column2",
    "type": "TEXT_NUMBER",
    "validation": false,
    "width": 150
  }, {
    "id": 1988921518253956,
    "index": 2,
    "title": "Column3",
    "type": "TEXT_NUMBER",
    "validation": false,
    "width": 150
  }, {
    "id": 6492521145624452,
    "index": 3,
    "title": "Column4",
    "type": "TEXT_NUMBER",
    "validation": false,
    "width": 150
  }, {
    "id": 4240721331939204,
    "index": 4,
    "title": "Column5",
    "type": "TEXT_NUMBER",
    "validation": false,
    "width": 150
  }, {
    "id": 8744320959309700,
    "index": 5,
    "title": "Column6",
    "type": "TEXT_NUMBER",
    "validation": false,
    "width": 150
  }],
  "rows": 2018 - 03 - 08 T21: 09: 18.932 Z f657fe40 - 2314 - 11e8 - 8273 - 19289 d6ed567[{
    "id": 573049024079748,
    "rowNumber": 1,
    "expanded": true,
    "createdAt": "2018-03-06T14:51:59Z",
    "modifiedAt": "2018-03-06T14:51:59Z",
    "cells": [{
      "columnId": 3114821425096580,
      "value": 123456.0,
      "displayValue": "$123,456.00"
    }, {
      "columnId": 7618421052467076
    }, {
      "columnId": 1988921518253956
    }, {
      "columnId": 6492521145624452
    }, {
      "columnId": 4240721331939204
    }, {
      "columnId": 8744320959309700
    }]
  }]
}
```

Comment: [so] is *not* a free code writing service. You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding Im not expecting anyone to write code for me. Im asking for suggestions on methods of accomplishing what I am trying to do.

Comment: You will have to make the attempt yourself. If you get stuck update your question with what you have tried and where/why it is not working. See [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from your description which strings you're trying to concatenate -- whole blobs of JSON, certain strings from within the JSON?

I can at least say that an efficient way to concatenate strings is to push them all into an array, then `join` the array into one string.

```
var builder = [];
builder.push(string1);
builder.push(string2);
builder.push(string3);
...
var result = builder.join('');
```

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "get in an array" either, but if you're talking about turning all of one string into an array with each character as a individual item, `string.split('')` will do that.

Comment: var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
  console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
  console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function (load) {
  console.log(load);


  });
});                              This is the request that I am sending out. When the data "load" comes back in comes back in chunks almost at the same time but delayed enough that when I start processing it is using the second batch not the first. In other languages I could Gather up to a delimeter but not sure how to accomplish this in JS.